# unable to apt-get -y build-dep php5 php5-mcrypt

Tags: 16.04, apache2, php

when I try to do "apt-get -y build-dep php5 php5-mcrypt"

the resault is :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Picking 'php-mcrypt' as source package instead of 'php5-mcrypt'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
builddeps:php-mcrypt : Depends: debhelper (>= 5) but it is not going to be     installed
                       Depends: php5-dev (>= 5.3.3) but it is not going to be installed
 builddeps:php5 : Depends: apache2-prefork-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: debhelper (>= 5) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libapr1-dev (>= 1.2.7-8) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libcurl4-openssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libenchant-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libevent-dev (>= 1.4.11) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libfreetype6-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgcrypt11-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgd2-xpm-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libglib2.0-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libgmp3-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmagic-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libmysqlclient-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpam0g-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpng12-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpq-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libpspell-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsasl2-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libsnmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libssl-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libt1-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libwrap0-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxml2-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libxslt1-dev (>= 1.0.18) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: mysql-client-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: locales-all but it is not installable or
  language-pack-de but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: zlib1g-dev but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libedit-dev but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

what's the solution

Answer (score 0):

You tagged 16.04.  Assuming you're running 16.04, the php in the repository is v7.

Try this instead.

```
sudo apt-get -y build-dep php7.0 php7-mcrypt
```

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
E: Unable to find a source package for php7 !!

Comment: sorry about that, I updated the answer, it's actually `php7.0`, not `php7`